# Java Compile and Run Multiple Classes on Linux

Tags: java

I have two class file in same folder, both in same package (package hw9;). I can run them in netbeans but when I try to compile in src folder

```
[user@manjaro hw9]$ javac * 
[user@manjaro hw9]$ java Hw9
Error: Could not find or load main class Hw9
```

I take this error.

Comment: Is the currect directory in your class path?  Look a Java runtime command line options

Comment: If you are using Linux: `pwd` helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile `Hw9.java` one directory up,

```
javac hw9/*.java
```

then run

```
java hw9.Hw9
```